# Cpanel filter encoding utf-8?

Tags: email, filter, character-encoding, cpanel

Please can you tell me how I can filter emails in cpanel global email filter if the subject is encoded :
Subject: =?utf-8?b?

Simple filtering if subject contains utf-8 does not work

I am a novice at regex so any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [webmasters.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).